# UnicodeDecodeError with pandas.read_sql

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 8: character maps to <undefined>
```

Am seeing the above error in this simple SQL query:

```
df = pd.read_sql(query,connection)
```

I tried the query normally on SQL developer and it works perfectly fine. I am really stumped here as to how to specify encoding in a read_sql call.

Am using Python 3.4 and pandas version 0.14.1

Comment: When you `connect()` to your database, pass the `charset='utf8'` parameter.

Comment: so am using cx_Oracle 5.2.. I passed 'encoding="utf-8" ' but it didn't like it:
'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 20: invalid continuation byte'

Comment: What is the encoding of the data in the database?

Comment: I don't know tbh.. how could I find that out? This used to work perfectly fine for more than a month running daily - its probably a new entry?

Comment: to get encoding `SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS`

Comment: then show me the value of `NLS_CHARACTERSET`

Comment: thanks! see this: NLS_CHARACTERSET: WE8ISO8859P1
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET: AL16UTF16

Comment: now try `charset='iso-8859-1'`

Comment: let me now if it work

Comment: trying - you still mean `encoding='iso-8859-1'` rt?

Comment: yes in connect() pass charset='iso-8859-1' or encoding='iso-8859-1' try both

Comment: happy days! that worked!! thank you so much.. btw while I was waiting, i tried 'latin-1' as well and that too worked.. I shoudl put some error handling such that it tries all these 3 going forward?

Comment: you are welcome sure you should have error handling mechanism

Comment: I have the same issue, and the same charset in my oracle database, but when I use cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'pass', dsn_tns, charset='iso-8859-1'), it doesn't work. and the same error shows. can you verify if I have passed the parameter correctly? I also tried encoding='iso-8859-1' but no luck. @Hisham Karam

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the proper encoding for your database is `iso-8859-1` according to oracle [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96529/ch2.htm#100150) 
so When you `connect()` to your database, pass the `charset='iso-8859-1'` or `encoding='iso-8859-1'` try both.

Comment: @HishamKaram I have faced the same error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: invalid continuation byte`. But, unfortunatly, none of your solutions helped me

Comment: please let me know your database encoding by executing this line ```SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS``` @LadenkovVladislav

Comment: @Thanks, but it's okay now. I just figured out, that i just had some corrupted non-utf8 values

Comment: @hisham Hey Hisham how do you find the encoding map from Oracle NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET ?

Comment: When i do `conn = sqlite3.connect(sql_path,charset='iso-8859-1')`,  I get `TypeError: 'charset' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`.... same for `encoding`!

Comment: I have the same issue, and the same charset in my oracle database, but when I use cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'pass', dsn_tns, charset='iso-8859-1'), it doesn't work. and the same error shows. can you verify if I have passed the parameter correctly? I also tried encoding='iso-8859-1' but no luck. @HishamKaram

Answer (score 2):

Python3.7:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(path_to_db)
encoding = "latin1"
con.text_factory = lambda x: str(x, encoding)
# do not preserve non-printable
# con.text_factory = lambda x: str(x, "ascii", errors="ignore")
data = pd.read_sql_query(QUERY, con)
```

[Pydocs on text_factory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.text_factory)