# Pandas UnicodeDecodeError while using read_sql

Tags: python, oracle, pandas, cx-oracle

I am trying to execute SQL queries using pandas.read_sql. It usually works, but for **certain** queries I run into this error:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1454, in _fetchall_as_list
    result = cur.fetchall()

    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried solutions suggested for a very similar problem here ([UnicodeDecodeError with pandas.read_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231498/unicodedecodeerror-with-pandas-read-sql)) but it didn't resolve the issue.

I am using cx_oracle library for the database connection.

I tried

```
db = cx_Oracle.connect(user,pwd, dsn_dict[dbname],encoding='utf-8')
```

but when I check the encoding using

```
print(db.encoding)
print(db.nencoding)
```

I always get

```
ASCII
ASCII
```

I tried changing NLS_LANG using

```
os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII'
```

but it results in the same error

These are the database NLS parameters:

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET    US7ASCII

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
```

I ran the same query in access and I notice this character in the query result, which might be causing this issue:

```
¿
```

Basically, I don't know how to set proper encoding to deal with the problem. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**SOLUTION:**

For reference, I solved this by setting

```
os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8'
```

I dont like doing this though. better solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With cx_Oracle 6 this should work for you:

cx_Oracle.connect("user/pw@dsn", encoding = "UTF-8", nencoding = "UTF-8")

Since your database encoding is ASCII you could even just set the nencoding parameter. If you are going to use the NLS_LANG environment variable, make sure to you the real UTF-8 encoding. That is called AL32UTF8 in Oracle -- for historical reasons!