# Character error reading sql database using Python

Tags: python, sql, database, tkinter, label

I'm trying to read a SQL database and show some information on a tkinter label, but the character 'ã' is being displayed as '?'. How to fix this?

This is the code I used:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
oracle_connection_string = 'oracle+cx_oracle://{username}:{password}@{hostname}:{port}/{database}'
engine = create_engine(
oracle_connection_string.format(
    username='xxx',
                    password='xxx',
                    hostname='xxx',
                    port='xxx',
                    database='xxx',
                    )
                )
        string_find_table = """ SQL View """
data = pd.read_sql(string_find_table, engine)
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

This is an encoding error, check this post:
[UnicodeDecodeError with pandas.read_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231498/unicodedecodeerror-with-pandas-read-sql)