# UnicodeDecodeError with pandas.read_sql_query

Tags: pandas, utf-8, oracle11g, decode, pyodbc

I connect to Oracle using pyodbc.

```
con = pyodbc.connect('''dsn=Oracle; uid='''+user+'''; pwd='''+pwd)

script = '''select 'NGUYỄN' from dual;'''

df = pd.read_sql_query(script, con)
```

Then my output is NGUY¿N while my expected output is NGUYỄN

Then I add those lines of code and run the script again:

```
con.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf8')
con.setencoding(encoding='utf8')
df = pd.read_sql_query(script, con)
```

It works, my output now is NGUYỄN as I expect.

But when I change the SQL script to:

```
select name from table;
```

Then the error occur:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 4: invalid start byte`

While I execute this query on Oracle normally and the output is 'NGUYỄN VĂN A'

My expected output is the same as the output that displayed in Oracle result (NGUYỄN VĂN A).

I execute this query on my database (select * from nls_database_parameters;) and found that the NLS_CHARACTERSET is AL32UTF8
and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET is AL16UTF16

I've read about the answer for the same problem at: [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231498/unicodedecodeerror-with-pandas-read-sql?newreg=6bed260243ef4772b56fac1a33fcf95e) but I still can't not figure out my problem.